# Punjabi Text is not appearing properly in Android

Tags: android, text, typeface

Below is my code where I am using typeface correctly to change the font for the punjabi but it is still showing incorrect text on Galaxy S2 and punctuations on phones other than Samsung. Not sure how can I fix this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), 
            "fonts/ANMOL_L.TTF");
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    txt.setTextSize(40);
    txt.setTypeface(tf);
    txt.setText("ੴ ਸਤਿ ਨਾਮੁ ਕਰਤਾ ਪੁਰਖੁ ਨਿਰਭਉ ਨਿਰਵੈਰੁ ਅਕਾਲ ਮੂਰਤਿ ਅਜੂਨੀ ਸੈਭੰ ਗੁਰ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ ॥");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try txt.setText("Testing"); And you will notice you will see Punjabi text. This is because the font you have chosen is not a Unicode compatible font. It overrides ASCII codes. Choose another font file.

I have tested AnmolUni.ttf and AmbarSlim.ttf files from http://www.gurbanifiles.org/unicode/ and they work.

Comment: From what I can see the "ANMOL_L.ttf" works with Punjabi : http://www.fontsitescript.com/demo/fonts.php?show_font=123

Comment: Simon, I have tried these just now it's the same issue as before. It shows the text in Punjabi but many words appear to be misplaced. For example note these words carefully "ਸਤਿ" "ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ" On the emulator or the phone it shows differently but on my S3 phone it shows perfectly fine.

Comment: Make sure you are using JellyBean