# Way to type any language and appears exactly the same in Android?

Tags: android, textview

I am making an app which shows an Indian Language (Punjabi). Is it possible if it shows exactly the same text on all the Android devices if my TextView is something like this: "ੴ ਸਤਿ ਨਾਮੁ ਕਰਤਾ ਪੁਰਖੁ ਨਿਰਭਉ ਨਿਰਵੈਰੁ ਅਕਾਲ ਮੂਰਤਿ ਅਜੂਨੀ ਸੈਭੰ ਗੁਰ ਪ੍ਰਸਾਦਿ " If not what's the best way to approach this?

Comment: I'm a little confused; is it NOT showing the same thing? Tell us what's going wrong. That said, I suspect that if you *are* having problems, you're encountering devices with incomplete unicode fonts. I don't know if there's a fix for that.

Comment: Please refer to this for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369246/punjabi-text-is-not-appearing-properly-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If the file is encoded using UTF-8, you should be fine.  But, don't forget that Android devices support multiple locales, so providing a translation is a good idea (unless you limit distribution to that locality).

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Gives details on how to add multiple translations to your project based on the locale of the device.